# Syntax Issue while Declaring select statement into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I run the select statement its working fine but if I defined into a variable then I am getting syntax error.

```
Declare @a varchar(2550)

SET @a='    
        SELECT 'ALTER DATABASE ' + CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' +
 QUOTENAME( df.name,'''') + ', NEWNAME = ''' + 
QUOTENAME( DB_NAME())    +
+ CASE 
  WHEN df.type_desc = 'ROWS' AND df.file_id = 1 THEN '.mdf'' )'
  WHEN df.type_desc = 'LOG' THEN '_log.ldf'' )'
  WHEN df.type_desc = 'ROWS' AND df.file_id != 1 THEN '.ndf'' )'
 END 
FROM sys.database_files df'

 select @a
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38 Incorrect syntax near ' +
> CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARCHAR(50)) + '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a combination of typing errors and wrong use of `SET` and/or `SELECT`. If I understand you correctly, you may try to use the following statement:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(2550)

SELECT @a = 
   'ALTER DATABASE ' +
   CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARCHAR(50)) + 
   ' MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' +
   QUOTENAME( df.name,'''') + ', NEWNAME = ''' + 
   QUOTENAME( DB_NAME()) + 
   CASE 
     WHEN df.type_desc = 'ROWS' AND df.file_id = 1 THEN '.mdf'' )'
     WHEN df.type_desc = 'LOG' THEN '_log.ldf'' )'
     WHEN df.type_desc = 'ROWS' AND df.file_id != 1 THEN '.ndf'' )'
  END  
FROM sys.database_files df

SELECT @a
```

As an important note, when you use [SELECT @local_variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) and the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned. So if you want to generate a complex statement for all database files, you need to concatenate the returned rows (using `FOR XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG()`). In this case, as @GordonLinoff commented, you may declare the `@a` variable as `nvarchar(max)`:

```
DECLARE @a nvarchar(max) = N''

SELECT @a = (
   SELECT 
      N'ALTER DATABASE ' +
      CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARCHAR(50)) + 
      N' MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' +
      QUOTENAME( df.name,'''') + 
      N', NEWNAME = ''' + 
      QUOTENAME( DB_NAME()) + 
      CASE 
        WHEN df.type_desc = 'ROWS' AND df.file_id = 1 THEN N'.mdf'' )'
        WHEN df.type_desc = 'LOG' THEN N'_log.ldf'' )'
        WHEN df.type_desc = 'ROWS' AND df.file_id != 1 THEN N'.ndf'' )'
      END +
      N';'
   FROM sys.database_files df
   FOR XML PATH('')
) 

SELECT @a
```

Comment: In addition to this fine answer, I would also like to offer an alternative solution: `SET @a = (SELECT ... FROM sys.database_files df)`. In some cases, this could be safer. Or it could also be combined with the declaration: `DECLARE @a VARCHAR(2550) = (SELECT ... FROM sys.database_files df)`.

Comment: @Zhorov . . . The SQL statement should be declared as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.  There is simply no reason not to use the maximum possible length when writing dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree. If there is no special reason for the `Declare @a varchar(2550)`  declaration and if this statement will be execute with `sp_executesql, `nvarchar(max)` is the first option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
declare @a nvarchar(max);

with file_cte as (
    select
      N'ALTER DATABASE ' + quotename(db_name()) + 
      N' MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' + quotename( df.name,'''') + 
      N', NEWNAME = ''' + quotename(db_name()) + 
        case when df.type_desc = N'ROWS' AND df.file_id = 1 then N'.mdf'' )' 
             when df.type_desc = N'LOG' THEN N'_log.ldf'' )'
             when df.type_desc = N'ROWS' AND df.file_id != 1 then N'.ndf'' )' end string
    from sys.database_files df)
select @a=concat(string_agg(string, ';'), ';') 
from file_cte;

select @a;
```